# Managing signed numerical macro arguments in Latex

Tags: macros, latex, numeric, curly-braces

I have signed numbers with the unwanted effects :

```
x+-5
x--5
```

(I don't know in advance whether the constant \const is positive or negative).
I created these macros to cope with the problem :

```
\def\plus#1{\ifthenelse{#1<0}{#1}{+#1}}
\def\cutMinus-#1{#1} % to remove the minus in front of a negative number
\def\minus#1{\ifthenelse{#1<0}{+\cutMinus#1}{-#1}}
```

Then with

```
x\plus{\const}
```

I get the expression correctly :

```
x-5
```

Goal : I wish I could use \plus and \minus as a replacement of the standard + ans - as follows (if possible without the curly braces which make things longer to enter and less legible) :

```
x\plus\const
x\minus\const
```

Here are my tests : \plus, \cutMinus and \minus have different behaviors depending of the way the argument is given.

```
\def\const{-123456}\\
%
*1**x\plus{-12345} ****\\
%*2**x\plus -12345 ****\\ % compilation error : ! Missing number, treated as zero.
%*3**x\plus-12345 ****\\ % compilation error : ! Missing number, treated as zero.
*4**x\plus{\const} ****\\
*5**x\plus\const ****\\
%*6**\plus-\const ***\\ % compilation error : ! Missing number, treated as zero.
%
%*11**\cutMinus{-12345} ***\\ % compilation error :  ! Use of \cutMinus doesn't match its definition. ! Too many }'s.
*12**\cutMinus -12345 ***\\
*13**\cutMinus-12345 ***\\
%*14**\cutMinus{\const} ***\\ % compilation error :  ! Use of \cutMinus doesn't match its definition. ! Too many }'s.
%*15**\cutMinus\const ***\\ % compilation error :  ! Use of \cutMinus doesn't match its definition.
*16**\cutMinus-\const ***\\
%
*21**x\minus{-12345} ****\\
%*22**x\minus -12345 ****\\ % compilation error : ! Missing number, treated as zero.
%*23**x\minus-12345 ****\\ % compilation error : ! Missing number, treated as zero.
%*24**x\minus{\const} ****\\ % compilation error :  ! Use of \cutMinus doesn't match its definition.
%*25**x\minus\const ****\\ % compilation error :  ! Use of \cutMinus doesn't match its definition.
%*26**\minus-\const ***\\ % compilation error : ! Missing number, treated as zero.
%
```

I don't understand all these errors. It seems that \const and -12345 are not equivalent. A question of internal coding of numbers ?
How shall I amend my macros to have them functional ?
More precisely : 
* \minus don't work, ever, with a macro \const
* \cutMinus, the way I use to get rid of the minus sign in front of a negative number, doesn't work either with a macros \const. May be there is another way to get rid of the "-" sign ?
* I wish I can use \minus like this : x\minus\const gives : x+12345 (with \const equals -13245)